# Is there a better way to create multable class varibles in For loop than globals()?

Tags: python

I want to see if there is a better way. I am kinda new to python. It is a way for me to try and use classes. Any help or suggestions would be nice.

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@company.com'

for Number in range(30):
        globals()[f"E{Number}"] = Employee('First', 'Last', 0)

print(E5.__dict__)
```

Comment: Using a `list` is probably a better idea.

Comment: FWIW, you can write a *lot* of Python code without ever using the `globals` function. It should not be part of your everyday toolbox, so to speak.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a collection of instances, don't use individually named variables; use a container like a list

```
Es = [Employee('First', 'Last', 0) for _ in range(30)]
```

or a dictionary

```
Es = {k: Employee('First', 'Last', 0) for k in range(30)}
```

In both cases, you can index `Es` with an `int`; a `dict` gives you more flexibility in terms of what kinds of indices to use instead.

Comment: How does it work/ how do I access the Variables. like I said earlier I am new to python

Comment: `Es[0]` would be what you wanted to store in `Es0`.